# How to explode string properly

Tags: php, string

How  to explode a string, for instance

```
#heavy / machine gun #test
```

in order to only get `"heavy"` and `"test"` ?

I tried with explode but so far I only got "`heavy / machine gun`" and "`test`"

Thanks in advance,
Jeremie.

Comment: You can't only do that with explode. With `explode` you explode a string by a delimiter. You don't have a delimiter here.

Comment: With `preg_match` with the regex `\b#\w\w+`?

Comment: Are all your datas structured the same way ? : "#type / name #something" ? To make it easier, you should write "machine_gun", to be able to explode with whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to explode:

```
$str = "#heavy / machine gun #test";
preg_match_all('/#([^\s]+)/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

This will basically find all hashtags in a given string.

Answer (score 0):

Re-explode your "first" part on spaces to get 'heavy' only

```
$heavy = explode (' ', $my_previous_explode[1]); // I guessed you exploded on '#', so array index = 1
```

Comment: This is encouraging an incorrect method. Explode isn't the right tool for the problem.

Comment: @FDL I'm not encouraging anything, considering the sentence with #test, it could just be an example or a training to learn how explode is working / can be used, I'm just answering "How to explode", not "How can I do see this in an effective manner". And, yes, regex would be better, I won't say the contrary

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is obviously more robust in this case but just for laughs:

```php
$str = '#heavy / machine gun #test';

$arr = array_filter(array_map(function($str){
    return strtok($str, ' ');   
}, explode('#', $str)));
```

[**» example**](http://ideone.com/8BbiZx)